# Why are there undefineds in my output?

Tags: javascript, undefined, console.log

Consider the following code:

```
function displayParkReport() {
  let title, part1, part2, part3;

  title = '---PARKS REPORT---\n';
  part1 = `Our ${data.all.parks.length} parks have an average of ${calcAverageParkAge()} years.`;

  data.all.parks.forEach(function(cur) {
    part2 += `${cur.name} has a tree density of ${cur.calcParkDensity()} trees per square km. \n`;
  });

  data.all.parks.forEach(function(cur) {
    if(cur.numberOfTrees > 1000) {
      part3 += `${cur.name} has more than 1000 trees. \n`;
    }
  });

  console.log(title + part1 + part2 + part3);
}

function displayStreetReport() {
  let title, part1, part2;

  title = '---STREETS REPORT---\n';
  part1 = `Our ${data.all.streets.length} streets have a total length of ${calcTotalStreetLength()} km, with an average of ${calcAverageStreetLength()} km. \n`;

  data.all.streets.forEach(function(cur) {
    part2 += `${cur.name}, built in ${cur.builtYear}, is a ${cur.size} street.\n`;
  });

  console.log(title + part1 + part2);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
---PARKS REPORT---
Our 5 parks have an average of 43.600 years.undefinedNorth Park has a 
tree density of 62.500 trees per square km. 
Central Park has a tree density of 102.174 trees per square km. 
West Park has a tree density of 70.833 trees per square km. 
East Park has a tree density of 100.000 trees per square km. 
Hasan Efendi has a tree density of 235.714 trees per square km. 
undefinedCentral Park has more than 1000 trees. 
East Park has more than 1000 trees. 
Hasan Efendi has more than 1000 trees. 

---STREETS REPORT---
Our 4 streets have a total length of 122 km, with an average of 30.5 km. 
undefinedBroadway, built in 2012, is a huge street.
Cavanough, built in 1992, is a normal street.
CrazyJoe, built in 2001, is a tiny street.
WestPark, built in 1956, is a small street.
```

Why is there random `undefined`s in the output?

Comment: `let part2; part2 += "stuff"; console.log(part2);` what's so strange about that?

Comment: sorry I am kind of a beginner. I know i was suppose to assign that variable to an empty string but sadly i didn't and wasted my time trying to figure out what to problem was till you guys remind me. After all, its not strange what so ever. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're using `a += b`, which is the same as `a = a + b`. Since `part2` and `part3` are undefined when you first access them, you're trying to do `part2 = undefined + '...'` which would lead the to `undefined` in there. Assign them initial values:

```
let part2 = '';
let part3 = '';
```

That way they aren't undefined when you first access them -- they'll be empty strings.

Comment: my bad. Thank you so much.